# different code behaviour with and without debugger at C++ .net4

Tags: .net, c++, .net-4.0, clr, debugging

I have WPF application which was migrated from .net3.5 to .net4.0. This application uses an old one C++ library (as I understand this is mixed mode library, means managed-unmanaged). Library moved to .net4 environment with some strange bug which occurs on callback call:

```
            if (m_pCANCallback)
            m_pCANCallback(m_pCANCallbackPtr, &rxData);
```

It passes rxData correctly if VS debugger is attached
and it passes NULL if I start application without debugger.

Here is callback function defenition:

```
void USBCANAdapter::CANDataCallback( void *pThis, RxData *pRxData )
```

So, at the body of this function pRxData is equal to NULL but it happens only without debugger and only at .net4 environment.

Just in case, callback initialization:

```
m_pUsbCan->DefineCANMsgCallback( (TUsbCallback)USBCANAdapter::CANDataCallback );

    void CUsbFt::DefineCANMsgCallback(TUsbCallback pCallback, void *pCallbackPtr)
{
    m_pCANCallback = pCallback;
    m_pCANCallbackPtr = pCallbackPtr;
}
```

Thanks a lot for any advises!

Comment: Is that really _Debugger present_ vs. _Debugger absent_ or is it _Debug config_ vs. _Release config_?

Comment: The problem reproduces without Debugger at Debug config or Release config. So, Debugger present vs. Debugger absent is correct

Comment: Turn the warning level on your compiler as high as possible. Now make sure that the code compiles with no warnings. The problem will dissipate.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved and the cause was in corrupted memory. Now I understand the value of this advise.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, 100% of the time where something works in the debugger, and fails outside of it, the cause is overrunning a function local array.

UPDATE:  For example, doing something like this will cause that problem:

```
 USBCANAdapter::CANDataCallback( void *pThis, RxData *pRxData ) 
 {
       char title[5];
       strcpy(title, "1234567890");
       // :
 }
```

(Or the overun may be in the calling rountine....)

Comment: James, could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: wow, C++ programming even more hardcore than I could imagine. 
Thank you for your answer